# eclipse HTML/JS editor

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, plugins, bada

I use bada SDK 1.2 and there is no HTML/JS editor.

What project do you recommend to add in Help->Install New Software?

I have tried 2 projects on sf.net(add jars to plugins) but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No HTML or JS editor? If youinstall the WTP from the standard Eclipse update site for your version you should have a (basic) one. Just check in the context menu of a file if there other options under `Open with`. If there is you can set the editor association in the preferences.

A visual HTML editor ships with the [JBoss tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools). Despite its name it contains tools that can be used and installed without using JBoss.

Comment: I don't need any WYSIWYG. But I have installed Eclipse Web Developer Tools from Galileo repository and I can't fine any new editor in "Open with".